# Strong converse of Kazhdan's property (T)

Tags: reference-request, group-cohomology, free-groups, geometric-group-theory

In his 1972 paper *Sur la cohomologie des groupes topologiques II*, Guichardet proved$^\ast$ that free groups satisfy the following strong converse of property (T): The $1$-cohomology $H^1(\mathbb F_d,\pi)$ is non-zero for every unitary representation $\pi$ of $\mathbb F_d$.

Is there any established name for groups with this property? And are there any references beyond Guichardet's article that study these groups?

$^\ast$ That's what I gather from secondary sources. I could not get hold of a copy of this article yet.

Comment: I suggest you ask on Mathoverflow. I have never seen this property discussed anywhere.